# CSS that act upon elements providing the base element exists

Tags: html, css

I have a structure that contains the following layout:

```
<!-- UL element not always rendered out -->
<ul class="alerts">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
<!-- /UL element -->
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
<script src="script3.js"></script>
<div id="z1"></div>
<div id="z2"></div>
<div id="e">
  <div id="e1"></div>
  <div id="e2"></div>
</div>
```

The ul.alerts element is dynamically generated by a CMS, and is dependent on other factors, and so it may or may not be rendered in the code at run-time. I'd like to implement some CSS on the div.e1 and div.e2 elements **if** the ul.alerts class **is** rendered into the code.

I've determined the following CSS, but I feel like I'm missing something...?

```
ul.alerts ~ #e > #e1 {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
ul.alerts ~ #e > #e2 {
    margin-top: -44px;
}
```

...going on the basis that if the ul.alerts element isn't rendered into the code, this CSS won't be acted upon, leaving div.e1 and div.e2 to revert to their default values for margin-top.

This however doesn't seem to work... Any ideas as to what I need to alter my CSS to achieve the desired targeting, based off my code structure?

Comment: Your CSS looks correct for your purpose. Maybe there are some other rules that have higher specificity, so those rules probably override the rules you've shown here. For testing, try to set something more visually obvious than `margin-top` — e.g. `background: red` or `outline: 5px solid red`.

Answer (score 0):

With form elements, pseudo-classes, and pseudo-elements you can do basic effects based on conditions and/or to indicate status.

- `:before` and `content` to display messages
- `:target` for basic click handling.
- `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` and `input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)` for persistent states/conditions.

#### SNIPPET

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + ul.alerts {
  display: block;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul.alerts {
  display: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#lvl1,
#lvl2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#lvl1:target {
  color: orange;
  opacity: 1;
}
#lvl2:target {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ #e > #msg:before {
  content: 'ALARM - ARMED';
  color: green;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-decoration: overline underline;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #e > #msg:before {
  content: 'UNARMED}}}}}}}';
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="chx1">Disable Alarm:</label>
  <input id="chx1" type="checkbox">
  <ul class="alerts">
    <li id="lvl1">WARNING!</li>
    <li id="lvl2">DANGER!</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /UL element -->

  <div id="z1"></div>
  <div id="z2"></div>
  <div id="e">
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <button><a href="#lvl1">Threat 1</a>
    </button>

    <button><a href="#lvl2">Threat 2</a>
    </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```